# how to update timer on windows form while application is executing

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show timer on UI such that when aplication star executing timer starts with 00:00:00 and when it completed its execution timer stops. Timer should show timing per second while running.

Comment: You can use a StopWatch to do this. Just call Stopwatch.Start() and Stopwatch.Stop() as appropriate, and use Stopwatch.Elapsed when you need to know the elapsed time. To show the time, use an appropriate ToString() for the Stopwatch.Elapsed

Comment: you need a  [stop watch](http://markashleybell.com/articles/creating-a-simple-stopwatchtimer-application-with-c-windows-forms)

Comment: i want to show timer on UI simultaneously while app is executing. can i obtain this thing using stopwatch??? like i want timer is running on UI and process is gng on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the System.Windows.Forms.Timer, which is created for scenarios like yours. You can read more about in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).

You should use the following code snippet as sample:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.Interval = 1000;
timer.Tick += new System.EventHandler(timer_Tick);
timer.Start();

private void timer_Tick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Text = string.Format("{0:hh:MM:ss}", DateTime.Now);
}
```

Notice that you should dispose the Timer when you do not needed.

Comment: i read about it but i am not gettign exactly how to use it. if u have any idea cn u plzz tell me???